# Help identifying an old 32-pin connector used by the Atari Portfolio

Tags: identification

There's a 32-pin card connector with guide rails shown on the right hand side of https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Atari_Portfolio_HPC-004_-_mainboard-93571.jpg - the main PCB for an old Atari Portfolio. The Mitsubishi memory card that would be inserted into this is "Bee" card compatible, pre-dating PCMCIA.

There's what looks like a small "BC" just above the bottom left fixing hole of the connector. The imaged can be zoomed to see it. This is the brandmark Mitsubishi Plastics used for Bee Cards.

Can anyone suggest a part number for this card connector?

There is an earlier version: Mitsubishi Plastics mp16k10. But it's not available anywhere.

Comment: There's a good chance it was custom made by/for Atari. Are you trying to replace that exact part or just looking for something similar for a different design?

Comment: please add a picture of the contacts

Comment: @Finbarr -  At the time Atari were sourcing standard parts from commercial suppliers. For example, the other end is a KEL connector from Japan (which is also where these boards were manufactured). And there was at least one other BEE card connector, see https://www.msx.org/wiki/Hudson_BP-0001 that predates the one that Atari used. I'm looking for the same or a similar part, but it needs to have the guide rails.

Comment: @jsotola - Connector contact configuration similar to https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/235393172872. A Bee card is shown at https://reverb.com/uk/item/41109098-bee-card-s-ram-256kb.

Comment: @Finbarr - It's likely that this connector was made by Mitsubishi Plastics, based on the earlier mp16k10 connector.